# Adding onlick event to multiple elements with params

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am dynamically creating a table of elements and storing them in an array. The following may seem like an absolute nightmare but this is how I have decided to sort it. My problem now comes to the `addEventListener` where I want to add an `onclick` event connected to `PlayMusic()`. I have tried a simple `.onclick =` and left out the `function(){}` but then the `PlayMusic()` gets executed immediately. Having the `function(){}` in there, when I click on one of these elements the first param (`i`) is the "last number used" (aka 22 out of 21 elements). How would I go about making sure each of these `onclick`s has the correct index in their params?

```
var thetable = document.getElementById("mustable");
for(var i=0; i<fullists.length-1; i++)
{
    fullists[i][2] = [];
    fullists[i][3] = [];
    for(var j=0; j<fullists[i][1].length; j++)
    {
        var row = thetable.insertRow();
        fullists[i][2][j] = row.insertCell();
        fullists[i][2][j].className = "musentry";
        var header = fullists[i][0].substring(0,fullists[i][0].lastIndexOf("."));
        if(fullists[i][1][j][1] != undefined)
            var title = fullists[i][1][j][1];
        else
            var title = fullists[i][1][j][0].substring(fullists[i][1][j][0].lastIndexOf("/"));
        fullists[i][2][j].innerHTML = header + "<br /><b>" + title + "</b>";
        fullists[i][2][j].addEventListener("click",function() { PlayMusic(i,j); },false);
        fullists[i][3][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that by the time the function executes, `i` already has a different value because the loop already continued executing. If you change your loop to use `let i` instead of `var i` (same for `j`) it will work, because `let` in the `for` iterator variable has a [special behavior](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation) where it actually creates another copy of the variable scoped to the *inside* of the loop on every iteration, so that copy won't change.

Another way, which is basically the same thing but done explicitly: Store it inside another *block-scoped* variable first. E.g. `const i2 = i` and then use `i2` inside the `function () {}`. Same for `j`.

Alternatively, write `.addEventListener(..., PlayMusic.bind(null, i, j))`. With `bind` you can create a new function from a function, where a `this` and arguments are already bound to it. Since the binding happens immediately and thereby captures the current values of `i` and `j`, that solves it too.